# Using both ground pins on uFL connector

Tags: pcb, antenna

I would like to add an [Hirose U.FL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL) antenna connector to my PCB. I have no previous experience of using them, so I would like to now if I should connect both of the GND pins to the PCB ground or it's enough to connect one of them. I found  this PCB trace. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should connect both pins for two reasons:

1. Maintain 50 Ohm impedance - With one pad only, the impedance is not guaranteed to be 50 Ohms.
2. Mechanical strength - A single pad is more likely to fail than two pads when pulling out the mating connector.